# How to change the host name of the ubuntu server running oracle xe

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-xe

I have a oracle 11g XE instance running under ubuntu server. I tried changing the hostname of the server by modifying the host name in `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/hosts`, `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` but the oracle-xe instance fails to start after reboot. Any idea which configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Oracle starts with only certain services / functionalities not working properly... If that's the case and your Oracle instance partially failed to start you can get some more information about running listeners by invoking the `lsnrctl` command line utility and then using the `status` command.

You can also look for clues in the Oracle log files under `<oracle-install>/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/<hostname>/listener/alert/log.xml` - you should definitely have one for your old hostname and you might have another one created for your new hostname as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and solved it just rename your listner.ora and restart, it will change the setting for the new host name

see my explanation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107343/oracle-xe-stops-working-when-host-name-chages/46107344#46107344)